# Where are the daily builds for Chromium for 12.04?

Tags: apt, chromium, software-sources

I am running now Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin but i still have today problem with this sources for chromium. Anyone have the Daily-Dev apt sources for chromium?

> Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromiumdaily/dev/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources

Answer (score 6):

Following up on @SirCharlo's comment. It seems that of the [four chromium channels](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily) the only ones with a Precise Pangolin build as of this writing are the [Stable](http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu/dists/) and [Beta](http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/beta/ubuntu/dists/) ones.

So you can remove the ppa you already added as using the rm above.

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*chromium*
```

Alternately, you can use ppa-purge or the 
[Y PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager)  gui, double clicking on "Remove a PPA."

Then install one of the available channel's builds. So to get the one from beta:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/beta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

I guess this will do until the Precise builds are available for more bleeding edge dev/daily channels again. At least there's no "failed to fetch" error and it gets updated periodically.

Answer (score 3):

### Alternative Chromium PPA

The PPAs above are not being updated at all. Alex Shkop has taken up responsibility to keep a better, more updated PPA set for chromium. They include:

- [Chromium Stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Ea-v-shkop/+archive/chromium) (currently at *21.0.1180.79*)
- [Chromium Dev](https://launchpad.net/%7Ea-v-shkop/+archive/chromium-dev) (currently at *23.0.1246*)

You can purge your older PPA using `ppa-purge` command.

**Note**: The above PPAs are only for 12.04 at the moment.

### Daily Builds

For the daily builds, you can use the [Chromium Continuous Build](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html) site to get the binary for your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*chromium*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Same Problem after update

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: It would seem that the chromium-daily PPA doesn't contain builds for Precise yet! Check it out yourself [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/). I'm sure they'll get to it soon, though.

Comment: Oh yes you are totally right !

Comment: PPA is now officially dead, as it will tell you when you try and add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install google-chrome-unstable if you want something similar to the chromium daily builds, from the official Google repositories.
Here is the list: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome